# Синхронизация imap (клиент-сервер) c#

Tags: c#, imap

Добрый день, стоит такая цель : синхронизироваться с почтой и иметь возможность загружать/скачивать письма. Есть ли такая возможность ? желательно средствами c#

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос: есть. И судя по прикреплённым тегам Вы уже что пробовали с imap?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6711407/6808809 Хороший вроде пример того, как получить письма.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, а есть пример, как загрузить письмо обратно в inbox ?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan подключение к почте с имап и получение письма проблем не вызывает, но вот, как загрузить письмо в inbox не понятно

Comment: чтобы письмо не удалялось после скачивания, нужно указать это в настройках учетной записи на сервере. Это одинаково работает и на IMAP, и на POP. Загрузить обратно не получится, хотя я могу и ошибаться, давно с почтовыми серверами не играл